# Best multiple AP office wifi setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssid

What's the best wifi configuration for a 3k sq ft office with 30 people? Ideally we'll using multiple broadband connections and everyone can roam the office without switching networks.

Is it possible to just set up two internet connections at opposite ends of the office with the same SSID, security, and password? Any concerns or best practices?

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach to this is to totally separate the functions of "Router" (which is not a WiFi device despite common misusage to imply that it is) and "Access Point" (the WiFi Device, or devices.)

Consumer-grade "WiFi Routers" are a router (generally of no great note) in the same box with an access point, and sometimes a small switch.

You need a router of considerably more sophistication - there are many options that work, ranging from "free" to tens of thousands of dollars. I'll suggest (but note that it's only a suggestion and there are many others) pfSense as one free (software - you do need to provide a box to run it on) option which can handle multiple WAN connections.

Then you need some access points to deliver WiFi from your wired network. If you stick with "Access points" rather than "routers" you're already halfway along the road to probably getting something of better quality than most consumer junk, but "shopping questions" are not OK here (they are in chat, I believe) so I'll skip recommending a brand.

Answer (score 0):

Just install one main wireless router, then put the other in [bridge mode](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110/~/when-to-put-modem-into-bridge-mode). Make sure the extended one is configured to the LAN (not WAN) interface of the main device and you only have one actual DHCP server. Also take into account who's where in the office. If you have an entire dead corner in your office, there's no need to take that into account when you place it.

EDIT: AP works too. Probably more cost effective.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The issue I have is that one broadband connection isn't sufficient bandwith for the entire office. I'm trying to figure out how to set this up with two separate accounts.

Comment: I have very limited IT experience compared to others who provide answers (which is one hell of a disclaimer), but wouldn't you then pay for more bandwidth, not make a separate account? Or is there something I'm missing?